# how to write dictionary table to text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, text, csv

```
dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 
   'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}
```

and I did

```
for k,v in dic.items():    
    a,b = k.split(':')    
    print a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v
```

to get this,

```
S00         D58          1    
M23         Q14          1   
S43         H52          84   
S43         H53          2   
S43         H50          5   
S43         H57          1   
M87         E11          10
```

I wanted to save this table to tab delimited text file. so I tried

```
data = a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v    
f.write(str(data))    
f.close()
```

but I got

```
('S00', 'D58', 1)('M23', 'Q14', 1)('S43', 'H52', 84)('S43', 'H53', 2)('S43', 'H50', 5)('S43', 'H57', 1)('M87', 'E11', 10)
```

instead of the tab-delimited table that I wanted?

How can I get my file output to match what I printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do something like:

```
data = 1,2,3
#or
data = a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v
```

the information ends up being packed into a tuple, to unpack it in the same fashion that the `print` statement does in python 2 you can do:

```
f.write(" ".join(data) + "\n")
```

This makes a string of each element in data seperated by a space followed by the newline character. (basically what `print` does automatically)

There is also a syntax that `print` has which lets you print stuff to a different file like this:

```
print >>f, a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v
```

Getting rid of this confusing syntax and preventing the exact issue you encountered are some of the reasons `print` was converted to a function in python 3, the new syntax is like this:

```
data = a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v
print(*data, file=f)
#or
print(a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v, file=f)
```

If you would prefer using this notation for print statements without changing versions you can add this as the first line of the file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Pandas' way. The dictionary is transformed into a DataFrame with columns `key` and `val`, containing keys and values of the dictionary. Then a second dataframe is created by splitting the `key` column in two columns, according to the string separator `:`. Finally, the two dataframes are merged and exported to TSV file:

```py
dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}
    
originalDF = pd.DataFrame(dic.items()).rename(columns={0: 'key', 1: 'val'})
split_keysDF = pd.DataFrame(originalDF['key'].str.split(':').tolist())
finalDF = split_keysDF.join(originalDF['val'])

finalDF.to_csv('test.tsv', '\t', header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of padded strings, just create a single padded string.

```
with open('/path/to/dest/file', 'w') as dest:
    for k, v in dic.items():
        a, b = k.split(':')
        data = '{a}{b}{v}'.format(a=a.ljust(30), b=b.ljust(30), v=v)
        data = '{:<30}{:<30}{}'.fomat(a, b, v)
        print data
        dest.write('%s\n' % data)
```

Comment: you may consider instead using `data = '{a:<30}{b:<30}{v}'.fomat(a=a, b=b, v=v)`  or even better `data = '{:<30}{:<30}{}'.fomat(a, b, v)`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library that is useful for this. You can use the built-in `"excel-tab"` dialect to output tab delimited data instead of comma delimited data.

```
import csv

dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 
   'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}

with open("output.tsv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect="excel-tab")
    for key, value in dic.items():
        a, b = key.split(":", 1)
        writer.writerow((a, b, value))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}

df = pd.Dataframe(dic)
df.to_csv('test.tsv', '\t', index=False)
```

Comment: Current answer is incorrect. The correct way of importing the dictionary into a DataFrame is `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')`. And then it can be exporrted to a file with `df.to_csv('test.tsv', '\t', header=False, index=True)`